# Верстка списка, не могу расположить правильно элемент

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Добрых времени суток, помоги, пожалуйста, сверстать такой список, проблема возникает с линиями.

Вот моя попытка:

```css
.description-list {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 550px;
}

.description-list__item {
  font-weight: 500;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.description-list__subtitle {
  width: 100%;
}

.description-list__line {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 3px;
  display: block;
  min-width: 180px;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.description-list__description {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="description-list">
  <li class="description-list__item">
    <span class="description-list__subtitle">Дата основания</span>
    <span class="description-list__line"></span>
    <div class="description-list__description">2011</div>
  </li>

  <li class="description-list__item">
    <span class="description-list__subtitle">Реставрирован</span>
    <span class="description-list__line"></span>
    <div class="description-list__description">2013</div>
  </li>

  <li class="description-list__item">
    <span class="description-list__subtitle">Расположение</span>
    <span class="description-list__line"></span>
    <div class="description-list__description">Cebesoy Cad. No.28</div>
  </li>

  <li class="description-list__item">
    <span class="description-list__subtitle">Площадь</span>
    <span class="description-list__line"></span>
    <div class="description-list__description">4000 м2</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Вот какой результат должен быть в итоге:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Пример

```css
.description-list {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  max-width: 550px;
}

.description-list__item {
  font-weight: 500;
  display: table-row;
}

.description-list__col {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.description-list__col:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 100%;
}

.description-list__flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.description-list__line {
  margin: 0 20px 3px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.description-list__subtitle,
.description-list__description {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<ul class="description-list">
  <li class="description-list__item">
    <div class="description-list__col">
      <div class="description-list__flex">
        <span class="description-list__subtitle">Дата основания</span>
        <span class="description-list__line"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="description-list__col">
      <span class="description-list__description">2011</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="description-list__item">
    <div class="description-list__col">
      <div class="description-list__flex">
        <span class="description-list__subtitle">Реставрирован</span>
        <span class="description-list__line"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="description-list__col">
      <span class="description-list__description">2013</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="description-list__item">
    <div class="description-list__col">
      <div class="description-list__flex">
        <span class="description-list__subtitle">Расположение</span>
        <span class="description-list__line"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="description-list__col">
      <span class="description-list__description">Cebesoy Cad. No.28</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="description-list__item">
    <div class="description-list__col">
      <div class="description-list__flex">
        <span class="description-list__subtitle">Площадь</span>
        <span class="description-list__line"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="description-list__col">
      <span class="description-list__description">4000 м2</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

У @soledar10 ответ конечно более контентоадаптивный (слово то какое), но если по простому и с минимальным количеством разметки, то можно так:

```css
ul{
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  max-width:400px
}
ul>li{
  display:flex;
  align-items:baseline;
}
ul>li:after{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  flex:1 1 auto;
  border-bottom:1px dotted;
}
ul>li span{
  flex:0 0 auto;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 5px 0 0;
}
ul>li span:last-child{
  order:1;
  margin:0 0 0 5px;
  width:140px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>Дата основания</span>
    <span>2011</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Реставрирован</span>
    <span>2013</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Расположение</span>
    <span>Cebesoy Cad. No.28</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Площадь</span>
    <span>4000 м2</span>
  </li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Можно так :)**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.test__container {
  max-width: 530px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.test__subtitle {
  width: max-content;
}

.test__line {
  min-width: 150px;
  width: auto;
  background: red;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="test__container">
    <div class="test__subtitle">Hello</div>
    <div class="test__line"></div>
    <div class="test__more">World</div>
  </div>

  <div class="test__container">
    <div class="test__subtitle">Hello, world</div>
    <div class="test__line"></div>
    <div class="test__more">20</div>
  </div>

  <div class="test__container">
    <div class="test__subtitle">Mate</div>
    <div class="test__line"></div>
    <div class="test__more">Hello</div>
  </div>
</div>
```